# Get only unique words from a sentence in Python

Tags: python

Let's say I have a string that says "mango mango peach". How can I print only the unique words in that string. 
The desired output for the above string would be [peach] as a list
Thanks!!

Comment: Which part are you struggling with?  Splitting the sentence into words, or finding the unique words?

Comment: finding the unique words.. i can use to set function to filter out the duplicate words but that would mean that my output will be [mango,peach]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
seq = "mango mango peach".split()
[x for x in seq if x not in seq[seq.index(x)+1:]]
```

Comment: Look more carefully at the expected output.  They're looking for those words that only appear once in the input.

Comment: this prints only unique characters ['p', 'e', 'c', 'h']

Comment: good catch @Maddocks sorry I had omitted the `.split()`

Comment: This solution is O(N^2). Terrible.

Answer (score 4):

Python has a built in method called count that would work very well here

```
text = "mango mango peach apple apple banana"
words = text.split()

for word in words:
    if text.count(word) == 1:
        print(word)
    else:
        pass
```

> ```
> (xenial)vash@localhost:~/python/stack_overflow$ python3.7 mango.py 
> peach
> banana
> ```

Using list comprehension you can do this

```
[print(word) for word in words if text.count(word) == 1]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another solution using [sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(abstract_data_type)).

```py
sentence = "mango mango peach"

# Convert the sentence into a list
words = sentence.split()
print(words)

# Convert the list into a set. Only unique words will be stored in the set
unique_words = set(words)
print(unique_words)
```

Answer (score 0):

First - split you string with empty space delimiter (split() method), than use Counter or calculate frequencies by your own code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to find the number of occurrences of each word, then make a list of all words that appear only once.

```
from collections import Counter

phrase = "mango peach mango"

counts = Counter(phrase.split())

print([word for word, count in counts.items() if count == 1])
# ['peach']
```